# Calculating correct frame of a baked sprite sheet with the angle

Tags: c#, algorithm, math, rotation

I'm trying to calculate the correct index for an array of frames including pre-baked rotated frames.

So let's say I have a sprite with 2 frames and rotated granularity of 90 degrees.  My array would look like this: `frames[frame0, frame0 rotated 90 degrees, frame0 rotated 180 degrees, frame0 rotated 270 degrees, frame1, frame1 rotated 90 degrees, frame1 rotated 180 degrees, frame1 rotated 270 degrees]`.

So my array has `frame count * (360 / granularity)` elements.

The problem I have now is calculating the proper index.  I know the following: the current frame, the angle (in radians), the granularity and the amount of baked rotations per frame.

I have this code:

```
int correctedAngle = Utility.radiansToDegrees(angle) % 360;

if (correctedAngle < 0)
    correctedAngle += 360;

return _frames[(frame * _bakedRotations) + (correctedAngle / _granularity)];
```

But it only works when granularity is set to 1 otherwise I get division errors.  I also wouldn't mind getting rid of the conversion of radians to degrees.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

To make sure I understand what you're saying, you have an array of length nk, where n is the number of frames and k is the number of rotations you allow.  You are then given an index i and a rotation θ (in radians) and want to determine at which index the image you want to find lies.

Given that, this should take two steps:

1. Determining the base offset into the master array at which you'll find the block of images corresponding to image you want.
2. Determining the relative offset from that point that will take you to the properly rotated image.

Now, if there are k different rotations of each image, then every time you advance from looking at rotations of image i to rotations of image i+1, you will skip over k elements.  This means that for image i, the base offset is i*k.

The question now is which of the k images here you want.  If θ is stored in the range [-2π, 2π], then you can convert it back to degrees to get a value in the range [-360, +360].  However, this doesn't really play nicely with array indices, so we'd probably prefer to map this to the range [0, 360] as you've noted.  One way to do this that's pretty clean is to just add 2π to the starting angle before doing the conversion and them computing the value in degrees mod 360.  That is, if the starting angle is in [0, 4π], mapping it to [0, 720] and from there to [0, 360) is pretty straightforward.

Finally, to convert from an angle in [0, 360) to an offset, we need to see into which of the k different angle regions the angle belongs.  We can do this by multiplying the value by k and them dividing by 360, which is the integer-division-safe way of multiplying by k/360.

In total, given angle `angle` and `k` different rotations per image, the image you want can for image `frame` can be found like this:

```
_frames[frame * k + (Utility.radiansToDegrees(angle + 2 * pi) % 360) * k / 360]
```

However, there's a much cleaner way to do this.  If you store the images in a multidimensional array that's n x k, where n is the number of images and k is the number of rotations, then you could look this up as

```
_frames[frame][(Utility.radiansToDegrees(angle + 2 * pi) % 360) * k / 360]
```

I think this is a lot cleaner, as it more explicitly indicates that one of the indices you're using corresponds to a frame and one is an offset.  It also makes the math a bit easier.

Hope this helps!